# Woocommerce E-mail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

A client of mine uses a woocommerce webshop and asked me the following: i'm looking for a way to make the emailaddress of the customer in the customer details section of the admin-new-order email, a 'mailto:' link.

**UPDATE**

With your help so far i've found the correct file to edit (email-customer-details.php), but i'm not quite sure how to edit the file. So far it only states this:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $fields as $field ) : ?>
        <li><strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ); ?>:</strong> <span class="text"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['value'] ); ?></span></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The output gives al list with the following:

- Customer comment
- Customer phonenumber
- Customer e-mailadres

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via changing the `email-customer-details.php` email template that you can find at : `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/`

Just copy that file into your theme like `your-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-customer-details.php` and do the changes over there as you need.

[Reference link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However i'm still not quite sure how to make the e-mail a mailto link.

Comment: Just check $field['label'] , if that is email then add <a> tag to $field['value']

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm gonna need some more help with this. I'll edit my original question.